# How to improve corda performance while creating 1000 or more corda states?

Tags: corda

I am creating 1000 corda states of one type. After that I am creating another state of different type referencing theses states from the vault. In other words, I am packaging these 1000 states in another single state. 
When I run the application, creation of 1000 states is taking approximately 30-40 seconds but after that when I create that package state it is taking around 6.5 to 7 minutes.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: If you can reduce it to a minimal reproducible test case then that will help us profile it here.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Corda V3. See https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/2609.